# Is this the best way to place some shapes on my page

Tags: html, css

I need to put some padding areas on my page. I use these areas, adjust the z-index and have them appear above or below other areas. I have set up the CSS and then I make them appear on the page as follows:

```
<div id="pd1"></div>
<div id="pd2"></div>  
<div id="pd3"></div>
<div id="pd4"></div>
<div id="pd5"></div>
```

But is this the best way to do it? Are there any shortcut ways to make square areas of varying sizes appear on the page?

Comment: Could you further explain what you want? for example an image or example page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more complicated shapes, you can also use:
1. SVG
2. HTML5 Canvas

If it's just RECT/SQUARE/CIRCLE - you can stick with DIV element.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the css border property as well, say a width of 10px or whatever you want, and also give it the desired color. it will give you half as many divs. (if im correct you are using all five divs for one box.)